# Pandas select rows where value is in either of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Title        Description
Area 51      Aliens come to earth on the 4th of July.
Matrix       Hacker Neo discovers the shocking truth.
Spaceballs   A star-pilot for hire and his trusty sidekick must come to the rescue of a princess.
```

I am want to select rows that contain the word Space or Aliens in either the title or description.

I can select rows that contain space using a single column but I am unsure of how to include the second column.

```
   words_of_interest = ["Space", "Aliens"]
   df[df["Title"].str.contains("|".join(words_of_interest))]


   Title        Description
   Area 51      Aliens come to earth on the 4th of July.
   Spaceballs   A star-pilot for hire and his trusty sidekick must come to the rescue of a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `str.contains` on both columns then aggregate boolean mask with `any(axis=1)`:

```
words_of_interest = ["Space", "Aliens"]
pat = '|'.join(words_of_interest)
mask = df[['Title', 'Description']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(pat)).any(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df[mask]
        Title                                        Description
0     Area 51           Aliens come to earth on the 4th of July.
2  Spaceballs  A star-pilot for hire and his trusty sidekick ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the options :

```
m = df.stack().str.contains("|".join(words_of_interest)).unstack().any(axis=1)
​
out = df.loc[m]​
```

Another one using `re` with a *listcomp* :

```
import re 

m = [bool(re.search("|".join(words_of_interest), str(v))) for v in df.to_numpy()]]

out = df.loc[m]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

        Title                                                  Description
0     Area 51                     Aliens come to earth on the 4th of July.
2  Spaceballs  A star-pilot for hire and his trusty sidekick must come ...
```